# How to contain field related data when Used group by in query

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, group-by, contains

This is my query which is retrieving work groups and sub training's assigned to the work groups

```
$companyTrainings = $this->CompanyTrainings->find()
        ->select(['id','workgroup_id', 'Workgroups.name', 'trainings'=>'GROUP_CONCAT(CompanyTrainings.sub_training_id)'])
        ->where(['CompanyTrainings.company_id'=>$company_id])
        ->order(['CompanyTrainings.id' => 'DESC'])
->group(['CompanyTrainings.workgroup_id'])
        ->contain(['Workgroups'])
        ->toArray();
```

Query result:

```
id   workgroupid   trainings
1         2         2,3,5
2         4         1,4
```

I want to contain names of the subtrainings from subtraining tables.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you're already containing and selecting Workgroups details, should be able to do the same for other tables.